# Filtering posgres table based on condition

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, pgadmin

I have connected to a postgres table through Jupyter, and am trying to filter it using a connection through psycopg2.

```
pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * 
FROM public."TABLE_NAME"

LIMIT 5''', cnx)
```

returns the top 5 rows of the table, however, I want to filter on a condition.

The condition is just an integer

```
pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * 

FROM public."TABLE_NAME" 

WHERE TABLE_NAME.COLUMN = 851

LIMIT 5''', cnx)
```

Throws an error 'undefined column' and suggests I meant TABLE_NAME.COLUMN which is exactly what i've tried.

Any insight on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: error seems clear, that column does not exist in your table? also you've prefixed your schema `public` to your call but not your where clause, might be better if you try to alias first `FROM public.[Table Name] t; WHERE t.Column = ...`

Comment: the column does exist, even when I go to my initial query and add .columns it comes up

Comment: its not a problem of column or SQL its an issue with replacing `condition` in  python.

Comment: The condition is just an integer

Comment: i see updated question. Do you really have a column named `column` ? Have you tried aliasing the table ? `pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * 
FROM public."TABLE_NAME"  t
WHERE t.COLUMN = 851
LIMIT 5''', cnx)`

Comment: I definitely have a column named Column. I can see it in the database and I call the column name after my first query which works.  I even get a hint, Perhaps you meant to reference the column "table.column", which is exactly what i searched. aliasing does not help

Comment: @CarterB have you tried removing the double quotes `"`? Also, in your case ou do not need to repeat the table name in the where clause ;-) something like: `SELECT * FROM public.mytable WHERE mycolumn = 42 LIMIT 8;`

Comment: Hi JIm. Still same error, however perhaps it is due to a capital letter in the column name? i type in where campaignId = 8, however the error states column "campaignid" does not exist

Comment: What is the best way to check the correct name of the column? The name when in pandas is not correct. Can I referance by index? I.E the 5th column?

Comment: nope. you can use `\d table` in psql.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
pd.read_sql_query(f'''SELECT * 
FROM public.TABLE_NAME 
WHERE public.TABLE_NAME.COLUMN = {condition}
LIMIT 5''', cnx)
```

Comment: This has generated a different error,  missing FROM-clause entry for table

Comment: I edited updated answer, used string formation with `public.TABLE_NAME.COLUMN = {condition}`, @CarterB this might work

Comment: thankyou for your help. Still same error. For reference the condition is simply an integer

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it like this -(Here cnx will be the value of column.)

```
pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * 
FROM public."TABLE_NAME" 
WHERE TABLE_NAME.COLUMN = %s
LIMIT 5''', cnx)
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is different from what I have tried?

Comment: i hope you can see `= %s`. Basically this %s will be replaced by value you pass in cnx

Comment: but cnx is my connection. Replacing it with the condition (an integer)  throws up  'int' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Comment: i see updated question. Do you really have a column named column ? Have you tried aliasing the table ? pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT *  FROM public."TABLE_NAME"  t WHERE t.COLUMN = 851 LIMIT 5''', cnx)